# CSS Grid - Grid areas stacking instead of sitting side-by-side

Tags: css, css-grid

I'm trying to create a dashboard using CSS Grid in my Vue application, but the tiles (grid-template-areas) are stacked on top of each other instead of sitting next to one another. When I hover over the grid container in devtools, I can see that it's divided into 3 columns, but all of the content is squished together in the first one.

I've tried changing the grid-template-column values; adding margins, heights, and widths; and changing position and display properties.

Thank you in advance for any advice.

- [stacked tiles with grid display property on containing div](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hL7SH.png)
- [devtools view of grid columns](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QP59W.png)
- [tiles with grid display property removed from their containing div](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LxNI2.png)

Vue HTML template:

```
<template>
    <div id="dashboard-container">
        <h1>My Dashboard</h1>
        <div id="dashboard-tiles">
            <div id="dashboard-tile-1" class="dashboard-tile">
                <img class="dashboard-tile-logo" src="../assets/example-img.jpg" alt=""/>
                <p class="dashboard-tile-name">Tile 1</p>
            </div>
            <div id="dashboard-tile-2" class="dashboard-tile">
                <img class="dashboard-tile-logo" src="../assets/example-img.jpg" alt=""/>
                <p class="dashboard-tile-name">Tile 2</p>
            </div>
            <div id="dashboard-tile-3" class="dashboard-tile">
                <img class="dashboard-tile-logo" src="../assets/example-img.jpg" alt=""/>
                <p class="dashboard-tile-name">Tile 3</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</template>
```

Vue Style (CSS):

```
    #dashboard-container {
        border: 2px dashed black;
    }
    #dashboard-tiles {
        display: grid;
        grid-template-columns: auto auto auto;
        grid-template-areas: "dashboard-tile-1 dashboard-tile-2 dashboard-tile-3";
    }
    .dashboard-tile {
        border: 2px solid black;
        height: 7em;
        margin: 2em;
        width: 7em;
    }
    #dashboard-tile-1 {
        grid-area: dashboard-tile-1;
    }
    #dashboard-tile-2 {
        grid-area: dashboard-tile-2;
    }
    #dashboard-tile-3 {
        grid-area: dashboard-tile-3;
    }
    .dashboard-tile-logo, .dashboard-tile-name {
        display: block;
    }
    .dashboard-tile-logo {
        height: 1.5em;
    }
```

Comment: Your code appears to be working fine.  https://jsfiddle.net/3x8gwef0/

Comment: BTW, as you're using `grid-template-areas` you don't need to also specify `grid-template-columns` with all-`auto` widths.

Comment: Thank you both for checking and for the information. I looked throughout my Vue app to see if there were any global styles that could be impacting the grid display but wasn't able to find anything (all of my component styles are scoped.) I wonder what's causing this!

Comment: Not a fix but note that the [<img>](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/dev/embedded-content.html#the-img-element) tag does not use and does not need a closing slash and never has in any HTML specification.

Answer (score 0):

As already shown, your provided example is working as expected. Perhaps your browser is serving you a cached CSS file?

```css
#dashboard-container {
  border: 2px dashed black;
}

#dashboard-tiles {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: auto auto auto;
  grid-template-areas: "dashboard-tile-1 dashboard-tile-2 dashboard-tile-3";
}

.dashboard-tile {
  border: 2px solid black;
  height: 7em;
  margin: 2em;
  width: 7em;
}

#dashboard-tile-1 {
  grid-area: dashboard-tile-1;
}

#dashboard-tile-2 {
  grid-area: dashboard-tile-2;
}

#dashboard-tile-3 {
  grid-area: dashboard-tile-3;
}

.dashboard-tile-logo,
.dashboard-tile-name {
  display: block;
}

.dashboard-tile-logo {
  height: 1.5em;
}
```

```html
<div id="dashboard-container">
  <h1>My Dashboard</h1>
  <div id="dashboard-tiles">
    <div id="dashboard-tile-1" class="dashboard-tile">
      <img class="dashboard-tile-logo" alt=""/>
      <p class="dashboard-tile-name">Tile 1</p>
    </div>
    <div id="dashboard-tile-2" class="dashboard-tile">
      <img class="dashboard-tile-logo" alt=""/>
      <p class="dashboard-tile-name">Tile 2</p>
    </div>
    <div id="dashboard-tile-3" class="dashboard-tile">
      <img class="dashboard-tile-logo" alt=""/>
      <p class="dashboard-tile-name">Tile 3</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I decided to show you how the result can be achieved using far less CSS and HTML attributes. In the provided example, there's no need to define a grid area nor to give a class or ID to every single HTML element.

```css
#dashboard-container {
  border: 2px dashed black;
}

#dashboard-tiles {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(3, auto);
  justify-content: space-around;
}

#dashboard-tiles div {
  border: 2px solid black;
  height: 7em;
  width: 7em;
}

#dashboard-tiles img {
  display: block;
  height: 1.5em;
}
```

```html
<div id="dashboard-container">
  <h1>My Dashboard</h1>
  <div id="dashboard-tiles">
    <div>
      <img alt="">
      <p>Tile 1</p>
    </div>
    <div>
      <img alt="">
      <p>Tile 2</p>
    </div>
    <div>
      <img alt="">
      <p>Tile 3</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Actually, given this example, it would be simpler to use Flexbox instead of Grid.

```css
#dashboard-container {
  border: 2px dashed black;
}

#dashboard-tiles {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
}

#dashboard-tiles div {
  border: 2px solid black;
  height: 7em;
  width: 7em;
}

#dashboard-tiles img {
  display: block;
  height: 1.5em;
}
```

```html
<div id="dashboard-container">
  <h1>My Dashboard</h1>
  <div id="dashboard-tiles">
    <div>
      <img alt="">
      <p>Tile 1</p>
    </div>
    <div>
      <img alt="">
      <p>Tile 2</p>
    </div>
    <div>
      <img alt="">
      <p>Tile 3</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you for the additional examples! This is very helpful.